# git merge master after reverting the merge

Tags: git, merge, branch, git-branch

I have a branch which was created from `master`.

I did some work in the branch. Now I decided to `pull request` the branch into the `master`, but there has happened a conflict. I decided to tackle the conflict by merging the `master` into the branch and then the branch into the `master`.

Then when I did it I got the point: I should have deleted all the conflict places before merging the `master` into the branch. So I reverted the commit which was about merging the `master` into the branch, then I deleted conflict places in the branch.

So, now time come to merging the `master`. And when I try it I see the message `Already up-to-date.` even though the master is not merged in the branch (since I reverted the commit which did it).

How should I merge the `master` into my branch in the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a good explanation of what is happening:

https://github.com/git/git/blob/0afbf6caa5b1/Documentation/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt

The gist of it is that you merged your branch once, and so history-wise it is up-to-date. You need to either merge something new (rebase your branch), or revert the reversion before merging again.

Since you seem to have botched your history anyway, another option if circumstances allow could be to reset your branch to a commit before the chaos and then just start over fresh. This of course implies altering history, which would affect anyone who depends on or works with this repository.